# Use `ctypes.string_at` to check the memory of a `memoryview` object

Tags: python, memory, byte, memoryview

In Python, `memoryview` gets a viewer for internal memories of `bytes`, `bytearrays` or whatever supports buffer protocal. If I use `ctypes.string_at` to get the value at the memory address shown by a `memoryview` object, I cannot get any information about the original object, like this(an interactive console):

```py
>>> from ctypes import string_at
>>> from sys import getsizeof
>>> a = b'abc'
>>> b = memoryview(a)
>>> b
<memory at 0x7fb8e99c8408>
>>> string_at(0x7fb8e99c8408, getsizeof(a))
b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x0e\x8a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00H\x10\x96\xe9\xb8\x7f\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

The results show no evidence of `b'abc'`. So what exactly does the memory `0x7fb8e99c8408` mean in the object string of `memoryview` object? Can we verify the memory directly to demonstrate that the `memoryview` surely reflect the internal memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the address of the `memoryview` object in memory not the string object itself (assuming CPython implementation). In order to see the string bytes you need `id(s)` or `id(memv.obj)`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import ctypes
>>> s = b"abc"
>>> memv = memoryview(s)
>>> s_mem = ctypes.string_at(id(s), sys.getsizeof(s))
>>> s_mem
b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\xa2\x90\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00CBT+\xa6\xce&\xa5abc\x00'
>>> s_mem[-len(s)-1:]
b'abc\x00'
```

If you're curious about the output you can read more about string object representation in Python [here](https://myshell.co.uk/blog/2020/09/python-string-object-representation/).